# Sonarqube authentication

Tags: sonarqube

I just installed sonarqube. As part of automation i am required to change the admin password through command line. I see there is a document to reset the admin credentials by running the query. I am wondering where do i run the query.

`update users set crypted_password = '88c991e39bb88b94178123a849606905ebf440f5', salt='6522f3c5007ae910ad690bb1bdbf264a34884c6d' where login = 'admin'`

I am using official docker image for sonarqube. I logged into container and don't see any mysql, sql, psql installed. So i which DB exactly i need to login and run the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SonarQube Docker images are using the H2 embedded database, and this one *must* not be used for production, you should configure SonarQube to use another database (MySQL, Postgresql, Microsoft SQL Server or Oracle).

Then you can run the query in one of those database.

You can also use Web API to change the password of a user such as https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/users (this will work with any database)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to refer this for your question - [Installing the Server](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server).
Basically, `<install_directory>/conf/sonar.properties` has instructions for setting up the database if required.

Comment: But credentials are already setup right as part of sonarqube installation. admin:admin is what it does by default i believe

Comment: You probably didn't go through the `<install_directory>/conf/sonar.properties` file. As pointed out by @eric-hartmann it has necessary information for your use case.

Comment: Yes, I went through but i dont see a the credential entries in property file

Comment: You have to set up a database. Add a user table and then create a user with whatever credentials you want. Then update the set properties in the `<install_directory>/conf/sonar.properties` file. [Installing the Server](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server) has the instructions for it.